# Inherited Ubuntu server will not PING: What am I missing?

Tags: networking, server, iptables, ufw, ping

**Update: It turns out, our in-house network suppresses pings. I demonstrated this by turning my phone into a hot-spot (thus changing my outbound gateway), connecting with a laptop, then pinging the servers, which worked as expected. ::pulls  hair out::**

---

I've inherited two Ubuntu servers that seem to be configured to reject PING requests. My goal is to re-enable pinging for diagnostic purposes.

### **Things I've tried to enable pinging**:

Based on instructions from [here](http://ubuntuguide.net/how-to-disable-ping-response-in-ubuntu), I executed this command:

```
echo  0  > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all
```

Then added the following instruction to `/etc/sysctl.conf` so it's enabled on boo. This instruction was *not* already present:

```
net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all=0
```

---

### **ufw**

Respecting `ufw`, I followed the steps noted in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16376101/ufw-allow-ping-requests-only-for-specific-host): In the file `/etc/ufw/sysctl.conf`, I found this rule. I did not have to add it.

```
net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all=0
```

I also added rules to `/etc/ufw/before.rules`

```
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

and `/etc/ufw/before6.rules`

```
-A ufw6-before-input -p icmpv6 --icmpv6-type echo-request -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Then restarted that service. `service ufw restart`

---

### **iptables**

I added some `iptables` entries I found by Googling. (I'm showing only the relevant rules in the list.)

```
root@tatooine:~# iptables --list
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             maskedpath.linode.com icmp echo-request state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW icmp echo-request

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     icmp --  maskedpath.linode.com  anywhere            icmp echo-reply state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
```

---

**So my question is: In order to enable pinging, are there additional configurations I am not checking?** Alternately, could the `ufw` rules be loading from a different file? (And if so how can I find that file?)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Have you tried to turn off UFW and then ping, and then flush your up tables and then ping?

Comment: Thanks @Brian. Yep I tried disabling both `ufw` and `iptables` briefly too fully rule them out, but it didn't make a difference. I just updated the question to reflect this but, apparently our in-house network here filters pings. So the servers probably responded to pinging all along. O.o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hops (Firewalls) along the route could filter icmp packets in between ping source and ping destination.

- Use `mtr` / `traceroute` instead of `ping` (or Ping next hop then after next hop...)
- Ping different destination and see if this works
- Ping from different source network

Comment: +1 to give you some rep--but my goal is to enable pinging. Note the first bold words in the post :)

Comment: thanks for the rep - hadnt expect it for "comment" - did you try ping next hop? maybe some hop filters icmp?

Comment: next guess (I don't use ufw): '-s' means *source* but it should be your external ip address right? So maybe remove source option or change it to your external ip. Hope that helps

Comment: I remove the `-s` argument as you suggested and restarted `ufw` but it still doesn't ping. Also, I edited my question to represent the removed `-s` option.

Comment: Hey fella--your remark `maybe some hop filters icmp?` caused me to consider if I could ping them from a different network. Using my phone as a hot-spot, I was able to ping them as I would expect. ..at that point I tried pinging www.cnn.com from my office system, no dice. So the culpret, apparently, is our in-house setup. I'll go ahead and accept your answer. Would you mind editing your answer to include your thoughts about questioning other hops along the route--just so it's more obvious to anyone else who might pass through here?

Comment: @elrobis can you tell if `-s` also prohibited pinging? If so maybe we should add this cause to question and answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37789/discussion-between-cybea-and-elrobis).